# Timeout for SDLNet_TCP_Recv?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-net

Is there any way to cancel a `SDLNet_TCP_Recv` call after some time when no answer arrives? Or are there alternatives to this function that support a timeout option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [socket set](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/docs/SDL_net.html#SEC41) with `SDLNet_AllocSocketSet()` & [add](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/docs/SDL_net.html#SEC44) your `TCPsocket` to it with `SDLNet_AddSocket()`.  Then you can use [`SDLNet_CheckSockets()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/docs/SDL_net.html#SEC46) with a timeout to wait for network activity.

Depending on the return-value you can then use [`SDLNet_SocketReady()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/docs/SDL_net.html#SEC47) to verify that the `SDLNet_TCP_Recv()` call won't block.

Comment: I don't really get it how `SocketSet` are supposed to be used. Should they replace a `std::vector` of `TCPsocket`? How can the single elements be accessed?

Comment: @user11914177: SocketSet is essentially a wrapper around [a POSIX `fd_set`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29).  You can't really iterate over a SocketSet though SDL_net's API so you'll want to keep that `std::vector` of sockets around.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use `SDLNet_CheckSockets`? How do I know which sockets are no longer active? It is returning only the amount of active sockets...

Comment: @user11914177: After `SDLNet_CheckSockets()` returns >=1 you iterate over your `std::vector` of sockets & call `SDLNet_SocketReady()` on each one.  If that returns true you're free to read that socket without it blocking.

Comment: Ok, that is working. Is there anything that can be done with the return of `SDLNet_SocketReady`? Can this be used for anything or is it just returning -1, 0 and 1?

Comment: @user11914177: Not sure I follow, you should already be using the return-value of `SDLNet_SocketReady()` to determine socket readiness.

Comment: Yes, I already use it, but if the number returned is bigger than zero does this number indicate anything else than just that there are bytes in the buffer?

Comment: @user11914177: Nope, it only indicates that there's bytes in the buffer.

Comment: Ok thanks for all that answers, now I know much more about SDLNet!